# C# error: 1061 'PlayerLook' does not contain a definition for 'ProcessLook' and no accessible extension method 'ProcessLook'

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I am getting a error telling me that 'PlayerLook' does not contain a definition for 'ProcessLook' and no accessible extension method 'ProcessLook' accepting a first argument of type 'PlayerLook' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?). I have retyped the whole script but I'm still getting the same error

here's the code, the error can be found on line (33,14)

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.InputSystem;

public class InputManager : MonoBehaviour
{
    private PlayerInput playerInput;
    private PlayerInput.OnFootActions onFoot;

    private PlayerMotor motor;
    private PlayerLook look;
    // Start is called before the first frame update
    void Awake()
    {
        playerInput = new PlayerInput();
        onFoot = playerInput.OnFoot;

        motor = GetComponent<PlayerMotor>();
        look = GetComponent<PlayerLook>();

        onFoot.Jump.performed += ctx => motor.Jump();
    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    void FixedUpdate()
    {
        // tell the playermotor to move using the value from our movement action
        motor.ProcessMove(onFoot.Movement.ReadValue<Vector2>());
    }
    private void LateUpdate()
    {
        look.ProcessLook(onFoot.Look.ReadValue<Vector2>());
    }
    private void OnEnable()
    {
        onFoot.Enable();
    }
    private void OnDisable()
    {
        onFoot.Disable();
    }

}
```

Comment: Something between the formal and actual parameters of ProcessLook() seems off. Can you post the definition of that method?

Comment: what do you mean by definition of the method (sorry I'm new to this kind of stuff)

Comment: Click on look.ProcessLook(onFoot.Look.ReadValue<Vector2>()); and then select go to definition. Post the first line of the function, not the whole body.

Comment: I'm sorry I am still confused about what you're trying to say. How can I find the definition of the method.

Comment: In Visual Studio simply right-click on the the function "ProcessLook" and then select "Go To Definition".

Comment: It says I can't navigate to the symbol under the caret

Comment: So then I would suggest that you search through all files for the PlayerLook class and post the ProcessLook() function within it.

Comment: The error is  saying ProcessLook() doesn’t exist (in the form you’re trying to use at least). Does it exist? If so, post the code for it.

Comment: *the error can be found on line (33,14)* - stack overflow code boxes don't have line numbers, but your visual studio does. Please help us out by telling us the entire faulty line (copy and paste it again) which is easy for you to locate, rather than leaving us to laboriously count 33 lines into the code

Comment: Here is where the error happened private void LateUpdate()
    {
        look.ProcessLook(onFoot.Look.ReadValue<Vector2>());
    }

Comment: I couldn't fix the error in the project, but all I had to do was recreate the project in 2020.3.27f1 LTS (or any 2020 LTS version) to fix it .

Answer (score 1):

Tick the "Auto-Save" in the Input Actions tab. This happens because when we added the Look action, it is not updated/saved in the C# file immediately. Thus, the PlayerInput does not recognise "Look" as a method